# How to get offsetTop of a React Child with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, typescript-typings

How to get a React children offsetTop using Typescript ?

Here my component:

```
export default class FadeIn extends Component {
  private onScroll = () => {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      // Get the child's offsetTop here and do stuff with
    })
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }

  public componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }

  public render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

I already tried to:

- use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(child)` but I get `Argument of type 'ReactChild' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactInstance'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactInstance'`
- use `getBoundingClientRect` but I get `Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'ReactChild'. Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'string'`
- cast child to `ReactElement<any>`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1.try to send the ref to the Parent Component

2.save the refs into variable or state

3.and then in componentDidMount method, you can get the child component height by getBoundingClientRect.